# Inheritance problems in Java

Tags: java

I have some problems with getting inheritance to work. In the parent class, the array Coefficients is private. I have some access methods but I still can't get it to work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Poly {

private float[] coefficients;
public static void main (String[] args){
    float[] fa = {3, 2, 4};
    Poly test = new Poly(fa);

}

public Poly() {
    coefficients = new float[1];
    coefficients[0] = 0;
}

public Poly(int degree) {
    coefficients = new float[degree+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        coefficients[i] = 0;
}


public Poly(float[] a) {
    coefficients = new float[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        coefficients[i] = a[i];
}

public int getDegree() {
    return coefficients.length-1;
}

public float getCoefficient(int i) {
    return coefficients[i];
}

public void setCoefficient(int i, float value) {
    coefficients[i] = value;
}

public Poly add(Poly p) {
    int n = getDegree();
    int m = p.getDegree();
    Poly result = new Poly(Poly.max(n, m));
    int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= Poly.min(n, m); i++) 
            result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i] + p.getCoefficient(i));
        if (i <= n) {
            //we have to copy the remaining coefficients from this object
            for ( ; i <= n; i++) 
                result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i]);
        } else {
            // we have to copy the remaining coefficients from p
            for ( ; i <= m; i++) 
                result.setCoefficient(i, p.getCoefficient(i));
        }
    return result;
}

public void displayPoly () {
    for (int i=0; i < coefficients.length; i++)
        System.out.print(" "+coefficients[i]);
    System.out.println();
}

private static int max (int n, int m) {
    if (n > m)
        return n;
    return m;
}

private static int min (int n, int m) {
    if (n > m)
        return m;
    return n;
}

public Poly multiplyCon (double c){
    int n = getDegree();
    Poly results = new Poly(n);
    for (int i =0; i <= n; i++){ // can work when multiplying only 1 coefficient
        results.setCoefficient(i, (float)(coefficients[i] * c)); // errors   ArrayIndexOutOfBounds for setCoefficient
       }

    return results;
   }

  public Poly multiplyPoly (Poly p){
    int n = getDegree();
    int m = p.getDegree();
    Poly result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        Poly tmpResult = p.multiByConstantWithDegree(coefficients[i], i); //Calls new method
        if (result == null){
            result = tmpResult;
        } else {
            result = result.add(tmpResult);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
  public void leadingZero() {
    int degree = getDegree();
    if ( degree == 0 ) return;
    if ( coefficients[degree] != 0 ) return;
    // find the last highest degree with non-zero cofficient 
    int highestDegree = degree;
    for ( int i = degree; i <= 0; i--) {
         if ( coefficients[i] == 0 ) {
              highestDegree = i -1;
         } else {
              // if the value is non-zero
              break;
         }
    }
    float[] newCoefficients = new float[highestDegree + 1];
    for ( int i=0; i<= highestDegree; i++ ) {
           newCoefficients[i] = coefficients[i];
    }
    coefficients =   newCoefficients;
}

  public Poly differentiate(){
    int n = getDegree();
    Poly newResult = new Poly(n);
    if (n>0){   //checking if it has a degree
        for (int i = 1; i<= n; i++){
             newResult.coefficients[i-1]= coefficients[i] * (i); // shift degree by 1 and multiplies
     }
     return newResult;

     } else {
    return new Poly(); //empty
     }
   }


    public Poly multiByConstantWithDegree(double c, int degree){ //used specifically for multiply poly
    int oldPolyDegree = this.getDegree();
    int newPolyDegree = oldPolyDegree + degree;
    Poly newResult = new Poly(newPolyDegree);
    //set all coeff to zero
    for (int i = 0; i<= newPolyDegree; i++){
        newResult.coefficients[i] = 0;
    }
    //shift by n degree
    for (int j = 0; j <= oldPolyDegree; j++){
        newResult.coefficients[j+degree] = coefficients[j] * (float)c;
    }

    return newResult;
}
}
```

Can anyone help me fix my Second class that inherits from the one above? I cant seem to get my multiply and add methods for the second class to work properly.

```
public class QuadPoly extends Poly
{
 private float [] quadcoefficients;
 public QuadPoly() {
   super(2);

}
public QuadPoly(int degree) {
    super(2);
}
public QuadPoly(float [] f) {
    super(f);
    if (getDegree() > 2){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be Quadratic");
    }

}
public QuadPoly(Poly p){
    super(p.coefficients);
    for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++){
        if (coefficients[i] < 0){
            throw new Exception("Expecting positive coefficients!");
        }
       }
 }
 //  public QuadPoly(Poly p){
  //  super(p.coefficients);
 //}
 public QuadPoly addQuad (QuadPoly p){
     return new QuadPoly(super.add(p));
}

 public QuadPoly multiplyQuadPoly (QuadPoly f){
    if (quadcoefficients.length > 2){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be Quadratic");
    }

    return new QuadPoly(super.multiplyPoly(f));
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get with the above code?

Comment: Well, right now, its that when I try to "super(p.coefficients)", the array coefficients from the parent class is private. Can you give me some tips with trying to get the add and multiply method in the second class to work?

Comment: I'm a little troubled at seeing 4 posts from the same OP on the same homework assignment all within the same 24-hour period.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476502/multiplying-polynomial-by-constant-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489384/errors-in-polynomial-class, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476502/multiplying-polynomial-by-constant-in-java.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the coefficients `protected` or use an accessor method.

I wouldn't throw a plain checked `Exception`. An IllegalArgumentException would be a better choice.

What is `quadcoefficients`? They don't appear to be set anywhere.

Comment: oops. That isn't supposed to be there. I was going to create a second array just for this class but that kind of defeats the purpose of inheritance. Is there a type of accessor method that can let me gain access to the whole Array? The problem I'm having is I'm not sure how to get the add and multiply method to work. I'm supposed to use the methods from the parent class as much as possible.

Comment: I see, you didn't write Poly. ;) You have to use the getter and setter methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

You put coefficients `private`. I wouldn't change this but I would add a getter method into `Poly` class:

```
public class Poly {
    //somecode here
    public float[] getCoefficients(){
        return this.coefficients;
    }
}
```

Then I would use it by the getter method in other code;

```
public QuadPoly(Poly p){
    super(p.getCoefficients);
    //some more code here
}
```

Even if you make coefficient `protected`,  you are trying to reach coefficients field of another Object, which is a parameter. So it is not related to inheritance and the problem.

Comment: If you do that they can simply be changed. I would strongly consider sending a defensive copy or an unmodifiable collection instead. Giving them raw access to a private mutable variable is a truly poor decision.